# How can I change a user's default group in Linux?

Tags: linux, users, administration, group

Being new to Linux administration, I'm a little confused about the following commands:

```
useradd
usermod
groupadd
groupmod
```

I've just finished reading the user administration book in the Linux/Unix Administrator's handbook, but some things are still a little hazy.

Basically `useradd` seems straight forward enough:

```
useradd -c "David Hilbert" -d /home/math/hilbert -g faculty -G famous -m -s /bin/sh hilbert
```

I can add "David Hilbert" with username `hilbert` , setting his default directory, shell, and groups. And I think that `-g` is his primary/default group and `-G` are his other groups.

So these are my next questions:

1. Would this command still work if the groups `faculty` and `famous` did not exist? Would it just create them?
2. If not, what command do I use to create new groups?
3. If I remove the user `hilbert` and there are no other users in those groups, will they still exist? Should I remove them?
4. After I run the `useradd` command above, how do I remove David from the `famous` group, and reassign his primary group to `hilbert` which does not yet exist?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The `usermod` command will allow you to change a user's primary group, supplementary group or a number of other attributes. The `-g` switch controls the primary group.

For your other questions...

1. If you specify a group, `groupname`, that does not exist during the `useradd` stage, you will receive an error - *useradd: unknown group groupname*
2. The `groupadd` command creates new groups.
3. The group will remain if you remove all users contained within. You don't necessarily have to remove the empty group.
4. Create the `hilbert` group via `groupadd hilbert`. Then move David's primary group using `usermod -g hilbert hilbert`. (Please note that the first `hilbert` is the group name and the second `hilbert` is the username. This is important in cases, where you are moving a user to a group with a different name)

You may be complicating things a bit here, though. In many Linux distributions, a simple `useradd hilbert` will create the user `hilbert` and a group of the same name as the primary. I would add supplementary groups specified together using the `-G` switch.

Comment: thanks. if i do `usermod -g hilbert hilbert` will that remove hilbert's other groups? If so, how would I keep those other groups?If not, wow would I remove him from his other groups?

Comment: Test it out and see for your particular environment.

Comment: @MIck's answer gets my upvote because he points out that you need to use -a with -G (otherwise any group you leave off will be *removed*)

Answer (score 15):

You need to read the `man usermod` which explains what happens with the various options:

```
usermod -g hilder hilder
```

will replace your login group from 'faculty' to 'hilder', as long as the group 'hilder' exists.  If it doesn't exist then you first need to create it with groupadd.

When you use the `-G` option you should also use the `-a` option to append new groups to the current list of supplementary groups that user 'hilder' belongs.  Without the `-a` option you will replace current supplementary groups with a new group set.  Therefore use this cautiously.

Answer (score 9):

To change a user's primary group in Linux:

- `usermod -g new_group user_name`
- terminate **all** *user_name*'s active sessions

To test your changes run `id` and look at the value of `gid=`

If the command runs without errors but the gid hasn't change you've missed the bold part of step 2.

Comment: `terminate all user_name's active sessions` is key

Answer (score 1):

answer #1 is good, still you could also choose to issue the following to add a new group:

`# nano /etc/group`

The downside of editing `/etc/group` directly is that you will have to come up with an unused GID (group ID number).

The following will allow you to change the primary group of a user.

`# nano /etc/passwd`

You locate the line of the user, and change the GID (group number, look it up in `/etc/group`), keep in mind that the syntax is as follows:

```
 <name>:*:<UID>:<GID>:<comment>:<directory>:<shell>
```

There is no downside I can think of to this approach (provided you know the GID), it is what I frequently use for local users, mainly because I use many different UNIX systems with differing `usermod`, `adduser`, and `useradd` command options.

It is a bit more manual, however does the job. Note that you can use `vi` iso `nano` to edit the files, if you know `vi`.

Comment: I think one should use the provided `vipw` or `vigr` wrappers, though, which set appropriate locks to prevent file corruption.

Answer (score 0):

To permanently change the primary group of the user execute the:

- usermod -g groupname username command

Or you could use `newgrp` for small environment and temporary situation.

Create a new user bob and a new group `dodo`.

```
useradd bob
```

So in RedHat/Centos we have UID=(ID_number) bob; GID=(ID_number) bob as primary group by default

```
groupadd dodo
```

Add the user bob to the `dodo` group:

```
usermod -aG dodo bob -make sure to use "a"
```

Next use `newgrp` to change ownership:

```
newgrp dodo
```

Be careful of your account to have a password and to be member of the future primary group. And the newgrp opens a new shell; as long as the user stays in that shell, the primary group won't change. To switch the primary group back to the original, you could leave the new shell by running the exit command.