# When a member of multiple groups, how do I set the default group for newly created files?

Tags: permissions, group

With `umask`, I can determine the permissions for newly created files.  But if I am a member of multiple groups, how do I set the default group for newly created files?

[This question seems relevant](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26675/15654), but its answers relate how the system administrator can change the *default* group for a particular user.  I am not system administrator, but just a mere user, and have no permission to do `usermod -g` even on myself.  So how would I proceed to set the default group for newly created files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To change your default group on the fly, use `newgrp`:

```
newgrp some_group
```

After running that command, you will be in a new shell with your group set to `some_group` and files that you create will be in group `some_group`.  `newgrp` may or may not ask for a password depending on how permissions are set.

**Related:** To find out which groups you belong to, run `groups`.

Comment: Just tested this, `groups` (at least on Arch) sorts them by numerical value, the primary group is not the first listed. Use `id` to get these details.

Comment: @orion I checked the documentation and found nothing to  support the claim about the primary group.  Answer updated.

Comment: It's important to note that `newgrp` launches a new shell. I don't think there's any way to change the default group for an existing process.