# How can I find out which users are in a group within Linux?

Tags: users, group

I've recently been creating new users and assigning them to certain groups. I was wondering if there is a command that shows all the users assigned to a certain group?
I have tried using the 'groups' command however whenever I use this it says 'groups: not found'

Comment: That is the [`groups`](http://ss64.com/bash/groups.html) command.  It is unlikely that you do not have it on Linux, since it is part of coreutils.

Comment: @ThomasDickey But it's possible – like on some NASes.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can use grep:

```
grep '^group_name_here:' /etc/group
```

This only lists supplementary group memberships, not the user who have this group as their primary group. And it only finds local groups, not groups from a network service such as LDAP.

Comment: Does not work with centralized authentication.

Comment: This could be really confusing probably because of primary/secondary difference. I think this should be avoided in favor of `sudo lid -g {group}`.I have a system where this answer lists 8 users in a group whereas `sudo lid -g {group}` lists 10.

Comment: See `getent` answer by @Murray Jensen below

Comment: This should *NOT* be the accepted answer. Modern Linux installations have multiple sources for user/group information - not just local `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` - e.g. `nsswitch` or `sssd`. Use `getent passwd` for user info & `getent group` for group information - this will cover all modern Linux configurations.

Answer (score 191):

I prefer to use the [getent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getent) command ...

> Since getent uses the same name service as the system, getent will show all information, including that gained from network information sources such as LDAP.

So for a group, you should use the following ...

```
getent group name_of_group
```

where *name_of_group* is replaced with the group you want to look up. Note that this only returns supplementary group memberships, it doesn't include the users who have this group as their primary group.

There are a whole lot of other lookups that you can do ... `passwd` being another useful one, which you'll need to list primary groups.

Comment: The other answers doesn't apply if you are not administrator and the group info is stored in other server.

Comment: This could be really confusing probably because of primary/secondary difference. I think this should be avoided in favor of `sudo lid -g {group}`.I have a system where this answer lists 8 users in a group whereas `sudo lid -g {group}` lists 10.

Comment: You can omit `name_of_group` to list members of all groups.

Answer (score 27):

Easier to do `groups [username]`

If you want to list all local users and their local groups you can do

`cat /etc/passwd | awk -F':' '{ print $1}' | xargs -n1 groups`

If you get "groups: command not found", it is likely you've edited your environmental path for the worse, to reset your path do `PATH=$(getconf PATH)`

Comment: It works for a particular group if `| grep {group}` is added and gives the correct answer unlike `getent group name_of_group` or `grep '^group_name_here:' /etc/group`

Comment: Instead of `cat /etc/passwd`, you should use `gentent passwd` so users in nis/ldap would still be listed.  The only drawback is that it can take quite a while.

Answer (score 18):

```
groupmems -g groupname -l
```

lists all users in the named group.

Comment: Note that `groupmems` is part of the shadow utils used on most Linux distros, however `groupmems` is currently absent from Debian and derivative (a [bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=663117) now fixed  but not included in any release yet (as of Nov 2016))

Comment: Also note that `groupmems` only deals with groups in `/etc/group` (not the ones in LDAP or other user database) and requires superuser privileges as it tries to open /etc/gshadow.

Comment: Despite the caveats mentioned above, this command is ideal for certain situations because it doesn't require additional parsing of the output (i.e. `cut` and friends).

Comment: This could be really confusing probably because of primary/secondary difference. I think this should be avoided in favor of `sudo lid -g {group}`. I have a system where this answer lists 8 users in a group whereas `sudo lid -g {group}` lists 10.

Answer (score 10):

`groups` command prints group memberships for a user. You can use `lid` command to list users in a group like:

```
# lid -g <groupname>
```

Update: On Debian based distributions the command name differs as `libuser-lid`. Both commands are provided by `libuser` package as @chris-down mentioned.

```
$ sudo libuser-lid -g lpadmin
kadir(uid=xxxx)
```

Comment: `lid` is part of libuser, which is not installed by default on many distributions.

Comment: What's more, on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, `lid` is part of the `id-utils` package. After installation it turned out that this `lid` does not support the `-g` option. I understand that Kadir answered 6 years ago, but maybe it's time to update the information given here.

Comment: @LaryxDecidua `id-utils` manipulates [id databases](https://www.gnu.org/software/idutils/manual/html_node/Introduction.html#Introduction), it doesn’t work with files such as `/etc/group` or `/etc/passwd`. Its `lid` is not at all similar to `libuser`’s.

Answer (score 6):

Works like a charm:

```
cut -d: -f1,4 /etc/passwd | grep $(getent group <groupname> | cut -d: -f3) | cut -d: -f1
```

Comment: Unlike the accepted answer of @ARG, this command lists the users having <groupname> as their primary group

Comment: this should be the accepted answer

Comment: I disagree. Because it reads users in /etc/passwd, this will not work with other nsswitch modules that access LDAP etc.

Comment: Didn't work correctly for me: I got 4 members in a group whereas `sudo lid -g` lists 8. @Bhavik The accepted answer is not correct either.

Comment: Works nicely, especially if `cut -d: -f1,4 /etc/passwd` is replaced with `getent passwd | cut -d: -f1,4`. As many people have pointed it out, `getent` will query non-local information sources.

Answer (score 6):

Some will tell you to install libuser (for 'lid') or members (for 'members'). But building upon the answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/349648/77959 which handled [this issue with login group membership](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/311119/how-do-i-view-the-members-of-a-group#comment547140_311123) I found another group not being covered by that script. So - here's the best of both approaches combined:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
        gid=`getent group "$1"|cut -d: -f3`
        list_a=`cut -d: -f1,4 /etc/passwd | grep ":$gid$" | cut -d: -f1`
        list_b=`getent group "$1"|cut -d: -f4|sed 's/,/\n/g'`
        echo -e "$list_a\n$list_b"|grep -v "^$"|sort|uniq
else
        echo "pass me a group to find the members of"
fi
```

Comment: It worked correctly on my system unlike answers involving `getent` or grep `'^group_name_here:' /etc/group`

Answer (score 5):

I am surprised nobody mentioned

```
id <user>
```

This command will give a list of groups the user is in.

Comment: Because - contrary to the title - the questioner wanted to know the users within a given group, not the groups of a given user, as detailed in the question. I now rephrased the title to match the contents.

Comment: Aaah, I see. I should have read the question text better. Thanks.

Comment: Even though , is it different from the actual question, everyone will find this too as a useful information ,  I bet !

Answer (score 4):

OP phrased the question to exclude the possibility of using the [groups](http://ss64.com/bash/groups.html) command.  Since that is part of coreutils on Linux, either (a) it was removed, or (b) OP is mistyping the name.

OP could have used `groups` like this, for instance:

```
for name in $(cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd);do groups $name|grep -w sudo|awk '{print $1;}';done
```

One suggested answer just grep's for the group name in `/etc/group`.  Sometimes that works as intended.

A slightly better use of [grep](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/grep.html) takes into account the syntax of [`/etc/group`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/group.5.html):

```
group_name:password:GID:user_list
```

so that only the part *before* the first colon is a valid group-name.  A plain grep without regard to syntax can (and will) pick up misleading matches from the file.  Use regular expressions to make the grep match exactly what is needed:

```
grep -E '^users:' /etc/group |sed -e 's/^.*://'
```

or using a shell variable:

```
grep -E '^'$groupname':' /etc/group |sed -e 's/^.*://'
```

However, that only lists those not in a [*default group*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26675/how-can-i-change-a-users-default-group-in-linux).  To add *those*, you need to take into account the password file, e.g., by extracting the group-id number from `/etc/group`, and printing the users whose default group matches from `/etc/passwd`, e.g.,

```
grp=$(awk -F: '$1 ~ /^users$/ {print $3; }' </etc/group)
awk -F: '$4 ~ /^'$grp'$/ { print $1; }' </etc/passwd
```

You could do the same thing using just grep and sed, but it is more work than using awk.

Another suggested answer proposed using [`getent`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/getent.1.html), which also is likely to be on a Linux machine (with Debian, it is part of GNU libc).  However a quick check of that shows it providing only the `/etc/group` content.

I (like most) do not have `libusers` or `lid` installed, so I cannot comment on whether it satisfies OP's conditions.

There is also the `id` program, which gives group information.  Someone might expand on that as a possible answer.

Comment: Or just `sed -n "s/^$groupname:.*://p" /etc/group` but that could still report wrong results if the group name contains RE operators (`.` for instance is not uncommon in group names).

Comment: GNU `getent` will also query LDAP/NIS... though possibly not when enumeration is explicitly disabled for the group database.

Comment: Note that `groups` would not help as it lists the groups a given user is member of as opposed to the list of members of a given group.

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
function members {

echo "$(getent group $1 | cut -d: -f1,2,3):$(getent passwd | cut -d: -f1,4 | grep $(getent group $1 | cut -d: -f3) | cut -d: -f1 | paste -sd ','):$(getent group $1 | cut -d: -f4)"

}
```

Lists primary and secondary members separated by a ":"

Answer (score 0):

This modification of user3717722 approach will list groupmembers in an NIS database:

```
ypcat passwd | cut -d: -f1,4 | grep $(getent group <groupname> | cut -d: -f3) | cut -d: -f1
```