# How do I view the members of a group?

Tags: linux, group

I need to view the members of a group related to an oracle installation.

Comment: What do you mean by "rights" in this context?

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835368/how-to-list-all-users-in-a-linux-group

Comment: Can we re-open this question and set it as duplicate instead? There is a good answer and many votes. Maybe just need to edit the question for clarity

Comment: @hanxue Dupes can not be created to the posts of other SE sites. It is because the sites are mostly independent installations of the SE software, using different databases. Possibly they are not very strong to understand why would it be useful.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use `getent` to display the group's information.  `getent` uses library calls to fetch the group information, so it will honour settings in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` as to the sources of group data.

Example:

```
$ getent group simpsons
simpsons:x:742:homer,marge,bart,lisa,maggie
```

The fields, separated by `:`, are—

1. Group name
2. Encrypted password (not normally used)
3. Numerical group ID
4. Comma-separated list of members

Comment: On Ubuntu at least, this won't include users whose initial login group is `simpsons`.

Comment: @jwodder A very good point, and true for all Unix-like systems. I'm ashamed not to have thought of that!

Answer (score 8):

list members:

```
getent group <group>
```

And what rights? On filesystem, sudo, ssh? On filesystem:

`find / -xdev -group <group>`

Comment: On Ubuntu at least, this won't include users whose initial login group is `<group>`.