# Is there a similar command like "lid" on Ubuntu?

Tags: users, group

On RHEL, there is a command `lid`, which lists group users, no matter primary group or secondary group.

```
[root@192 ~]# id user1
uid=1000(user1) gid=1000(user1) groups=1000(user1),1001(g1)
[root@192 ~]# id user2
uid=1001(user2) gid=1002(user2) groups=1002(user2),1001(g1)
[root@192 ~]# id user3
uid=1002(user3) gid=1001(g1) groups=1001(g1)
[root@192 ~]# lid -g g1
 user3(uid=1002)
 user1(uid=1000)
 user2(uid=1001)
[root@192 ~]#
```

But it doesn't exist on Ubuntu. Is there a similar one?

Comment: FYI, there's also `members` from the [members](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/members) package.  The output format is very different from `lid` (it just prints all member usernames on one line separated by spaces, without uid= details) but, by default, it also lists both primary and secondary members of a group. The default is `-a` or `--all` to show all members on one line, and various options cause it print only primary (`-p`, `--primary`), only secondary (`-s`, `--secondary`), or primary and secondary members on separate lines (`-t` or `--two-lines`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find out which users are in a group within Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/241215/how-can-i-find-out-which-users-are-in-a-group-within-linux)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/241219/70524 covers `lid`/`libuser-lid`, and the other answers cover other tools

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does exist in Ubuntu, but it’s provided under a different name:

```
sudo libuser-lid -g g1
```

It’s part of the `libuser` package, install that if necessary:

```
sudo apt install libuser
```

The reason it’s not named `lid` is that `lid` is provided in the [`id-utils`](https://www.gnu.org/software/idutils/) package and has a different purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The described functionality can be achieved using standard utilities:

```
for u in $(getent group | grep '^g1:' | cut -d: -f4 | tr , '\n'); do
    printf "%s(uid=%d)\n" $u $(id -u "$u")
done
```

**Update:** the command:

```
getent passwd | grep -E '^([^:]+:){3}'$(getent group | grep '^g1:' | cut -d: -f3)':' | cut -d: -f1
```

will retrieve lines from /etc/passwd corresponding to users whose primary group is `g1`. This can be combined with the previous command:

```
for u in $({ getent passwd | grep -E '^([^:]+:){3}'$(getent group | \
        grep '^g1:' | cut -d: -f3)':' | cut -d: -f1; \
    getent group | grep '^g1:' | cut -d: -f4 | tr , '\n'; }); do
    printf "%s(uid=%d)\n" $u $(id -u "$u")
done | sort | uniq
```

with the added sorting and removal of duplicates at the end.

This command can be made into a shell function for convenience, using the group name as a parameter:

```
lid_replacement()
{
    for u in $({ getent passwd | grep -E '^([^:]+:){3}'$(getent group | \
            grep '^'$1':' | cut -d: -f3)':' | cut -d: -f1; \
        getent group | grep '^'$1':' | cut -d: -f4 | tr , '\n'; }); do
        printf "%s(uid=%d)\n" $u $(id -u "$u")
    done | sort | uniq
}

# call as: `lid_replacement g1`
```

**Edit:** Updated regex to match the exact group name.

**Edit 2:** Updated to use getent(1) and added the function `lid_replacement`.

Comment: About the second point, that can be easily solved by changing the regex. About the third point, I'm not aware of what that "something" would be. /etc/group is a standard location in Unix-like systems to store group information.

Comment: About that first point, I wasn't familiar with the nsswitch mechanism nor LDAP, NIS etc. From what I could read in `man 1 getent` and `man 5 nsswitch.conf` it seems as if the nsswitch mechanism is using various sources to read the user/group information, with the ability to present it in the format of /etc/passwd or /etc/group. So, the easy fix would be to query the output of `getent passwd` or `getent group` instead ot the corresponding files.

Comment: `s/first/third/` in my previous comment. I addressed the first point earlier in an update to my answer.